# Request failed with status code 404 in react and redux along with axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, http-status-code-404, mern

Im confused why this is happening. It says "Property 'posts' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'.ts(2339)" even though in combine reducers the posts is there.
`like so.`

```
import React from 'react';
import {  useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Post from './Post/Post';

import useStyle from './Styles'
const Posts = () =>
{
    const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);// the error is shown here. 
    const classes = useStyle();
    console.log(posts);
    console.log();
    return (
        <>
        <h1>POSTS</h1>
        <Post/>
        <Post/>
        </>
    )
};

export default Posts;
```

When I run the program it shows
[This is when I tried to create a post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPXTw.png)

This is my combineReducers. My state also posts.

```
export default (posts = [] , action) =>{
switch(action.type)
{
    case 'FETCH_ALL':
       return action.payload;
    case 'CREATE':
        return [...posts, action.payload];
    default:
        return posts;
     }
   };
```

I have given posts in combineReducers.

```
    import { combineReducers } from "redux";

    import posts from './posts'


    export default combineReducers ({ posts })
```

These Are the actions defined.

```
    import * as api from '../api';

    export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) =>{
  try {
        const { data } = await api.fetchPosts();
        dispatch({type:'FETCH_ALL' , payload : data});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}

export const createPost = (post) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
          const { data } = await api.createPost(post);
          dispatch({type:'CREATE' , payload: data})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not telling you about an error in your React or Redux, this tells you that on your server, there is no endpoint at `http://localhost:5000/posts` that can be accessed using a POST request.

Either you have a wrong url or you have to check on your server implementation.